# Digital micrograph control of K2 camera

Tags: camera, hardware, hardware-interface, dm-script

I've been trying to use DM script to automate acquisition with K2. The rationale behind this would be to utilize the fast response of the detector for experiments such as scanning diffraction. However, when using functions for CCDs such as CM_AcquireImage() or CCDBinningAcquire(), each frame gives a 2.1sec overhead, which is ridiculously slower than normal CCDs. (In principle, each frame should be on the order of millisecond)

I was wondering if there's specific commands for controlling K2? I'd appreciate any feedback/advices. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the supported script interface does only give access to the single-frame acquisition mode and not to the continouse readout modes. (GMS 3.3.0) 
Please contact your Gatan representative if there are solutions for you.